# Is it chain of headers rather than a chain of blocks?

Tags: blockchain, block-header

We know widely used explanation of the blockchain:
"[Every block contains a hash of the previous block](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block_chain)". The sentence above implies that since every block contains a hash of the previous block, therefore every block should have a knowledge about transactions included into the previous block because every block has a following structure:

Block:

1. Magic No
2. Block Size
3. Block Header
4. Transaction counter
5. Transactions

Block Header:

1. Version
2. hashPrevBlock
3. hashMerkleRoot
4. Time
5. Bits
6. Nonce

However, every block does not have knowledge about transactions incuded into previous block **correct???**

As fas as I understand there are two chains in the Bitcoin:

1. a chain of [blocks headers](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block_hashing_algorithm) (a block chain)
2. a chain of transactions ([Prev Tx Hash](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction#general_format_.28inside_a_block.29_of_each_input_of_a_transaction_-_Txin))

Hence just to clarify, rather than saying: "every block contains a hash of the previous block", would not it be correct to say: "header of every block contains a hash of header of the previous block"?

Please correct my assumptions if I am wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Blocks contain a header, and headers are chained, so blocks are chained also.  Note the merkle root from your question: this attaches the transactions in the block to the header, making them a logical combined unit:

[image: block chain]

That is, you can't attach an arbitrary block to an arbitrary header---each header only attaches to one set of transactions.

You are correct that this expression is wrong: "every [valid] block contains a hash of the previous block".  That phrasing may be useful for non-techies, but if you find it in any editable technical documentation, you should probably change it.